# Where to create SQLite DB and how to create a Select statement in any page

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

new to xamarin forms with SQLite. I need some guidance on how to use SQLite in Xamarin forms. Below is the code.

```
1) Create Interface 

using System;
using SQLite.Net;

namespace SQLiteSample
{
    public interface ISQLite
    {
        SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
    }
}


2) Implementing ISQLite interface

using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SQLiteEx.Droid;
using System.IO;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SqliteService))]
namespace SQLiteEx.Droid
{
    public class SqliteService : ISQLite
    {
        public SqliteService() { }

        public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "myDB.db3";
            // Documents folder
            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);

            Console.WriteLine(path);

            if (!File.Exists(path)) File.Create(path);
            var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
            var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plat, path);
            // Return the database connection 
            return conn;
        }

    }
}


3) Class for Database Operation :CRUD

using SQLite.Net;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SQLiteEx
{
    public class DataAccess
    {
        SQLiteConnection dbConn;
        public DataAccess()
        {
            dbConn = DependencyService.Get&lt;ISQLite&gt;().GetConnection();
            // create the table(s)
            dbConn.CreateTable<Employee>();
        }

        public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            return dbConn.Query<Employee>("Select * From [Employee]");
        }

        public int SaveEmployee(Employee aEmployee)
        {
            return dbConn.Insert(aEmployee);            
        }

        public int DeleteEmployee(Employee aEmployee)
        {
            return dbConn.Delete(aEmployee);
        }

        public int EditEmployee(Employee aEmployee)
        {
            return dbConn.Update(aEmployee);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know :

1) Where is the place to create a database that can be used through out the app. This means I can use it anywhere in any page without recreating it each time I need to use it.

2) Will table be recreated each time in above code?

3) How to I do a select statement in any page ie CustomerPage.xaml or SalesPage.xaml ?

In WinRT, I used below code.  How to do it in Xamarin forms? Do I need to recreate SQLite DB? How to get the Path?

```
Using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath){

  var query = db.query<CashReceivable>("select * from CashRcvdTbl where Cust='" + Id + "'";

   foreach( var item in query)
  {

   }

}
```

Comment: Anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Here,

```
string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

This line in your `ISQlite` implementation points to your `myDB.db3 SQLite` file.
You can see this file into `/data/data/@APP_PACKAGE_NAME@/files` directory.

```
if (!File.Exists(path)) File.Create(path);
```

This line checks whether database file exists in above path or not. If not, then it creates this file once. This time it will be an empty sqlite file without any tables in it.
So, it will not recreated each time.

But, I think there is no need for this File exist check because, when you create a connection to the SQLite file, it automatically creates file if not exists.

So, it can be as simple as follows:

```
public class SqliteService : ISQLite
{         
    string dpPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), “myDB.db3”);
    public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), dpPath, false);
    }
}
```

**2)** Each time you create instance of `DataAccess` class, it will recreate `Employee` table/definition based on Table exists or not, as it calls `dbConn.CreateTable<Employee>();`
I generally write this line at Application Startup code.

```
public App () 
{ 
    InitializeComponent (); 

    //Create all tables here. This will create them once when app launches.
    using (var conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection())             
    {     
        conn.CreateTable<Employee>();
    }
    MainPage = new HomePage ();
}
```

This will simply creates a new table in the `SQLite` file if table not exists, otherwise it updates the table definition.

**3)** You can do a select statement as follows:

```
public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
{
    using (var conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection())
    {                 
        return conn.Table<Employee>().ToList(); 
        //OR
        return conn.Query<Employee>("Select * From Employee");            
    }         
}
```

In any page you can call this `GetAllEmployees` method to retrieve List of `Employee`.